# Vim auto turn off syntax highlighting when a file contains long line

Tags: vim

As long lines will slow down Vim when enabled syntax highlighting.

So, can Vim automatically turns off the syntax highlighting when it detects that a file contains a long line?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Kent's answer:

- The [`'synmaxcol'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27synmaxcol%27) setting can control how long Vim will keep looking for syntax. the default is 3000; I set it to 500 in my vimrc.
- The [LargeFile](https://github.com/vim-scripts/largefile) plugin can be used to disable syntax highlighting for large files, which is not *exactly* what you're asking for, but useful nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

give this a try:

```
autocmd syntax * 
        \ let a=0+system("wc -L ".expand("%")."|awk '{printf $1}'") |
        \ if a >= XXXX |
        \    syntax off |
        \ endif
```

change the XXX to a number, which indicates the very long line.

Comment: Nitpick: the `-L`  flag for `wc` is a GNU coreutils extension. AFAIK most other implementations don't have it (so this won't work on e.g. macOS or {Free,Open}BSD).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I don't have any experiences with macOS. awk can get the length easily too, but I was lazy, didn't write the loop. Thank you for pointing it out, I would modify it with awk if OP doesn't have gnu wc.

Comment: The needed awk loop: `awk 'length($0) > x { x = length($0)} END { printf x}'`